# Class as a Variable

Tags: java, enums

I was wondering if I could set a class as a variable, here is what i wrote, but objectively I get a compilation error.. So the question is , Is there a way to store a class in a variable ?

```
package Enums;

import Objects.*;

public enum Pointer {


    PLAYER(Objects.player), BUTTON(GuiObjects.button);

    Class point;

    private Pointer(Class cla){

        point = cla;

}

}
```

Comment: What is `Objects.player`, what is `GuiObjects.button`? Are they really classes in their own right? (btw, you should declare `Class<?>`, or even better, `Class<? extends SomeBaseClass>`

Comment: What are you trying to do, I doubt you need to write code anything like this...

Comment: @fgl They are classes in a different package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget the `.class` suffix:

```
PLAYER(Objects.player.class), BUTTON(GuiObjects.button.class)
```

In addition:

- you should declare `Class<?>`; and if all your classes extend a base class, `Class<? extends BaseClass>`;
- class names should begin with a Capital letter; package names should NOT.
- your `point` instance member can be `final`.

Comment: Package names should also begin with lowercase letters.

Comment: Can I make an objects using this variable?

Comment: @ExotickBoyPl you can, yes, but this is not recommended. Maybe you should rethink your design.